# How do you calculate the distance traveled and angle of a holonomic robot?

Tags: algorithm, distance, drive, robot

If I can tell the distance each of the four wheels of a holonomic-drive robot has traveled, how would I calculate the distance traveled by the robot? It is using 4 omni-directional wheels each on a different side of the robot, similar to this bot here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLRDQPrp2Ds

Also, I am interested in finding out the angle that the robot is facing based on this information. All I have found online is basically suggestions to use a gyroscope or accelerometer for this express purpose. However, I do not have access to either and am also very interested in how I'd be able to solve the problem algebraically. It seems quite challenging to figure this out because of the slippage each of the wheels experiences as part of the holonometric drive.

I realize that robotics are not ordinarily a topic for Stack Overflow but the ultimate purpose of this is to calculate this information on the microcontroller of a robot.

Many thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

We use [MLX90316](http://www.melexis.com/Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs/Triaxis%C2%AE-Hall-ICs/MLX90316-566.aspx) sensors to get idea how much motors have turned and compute everything from there. So no accelerometer stuff in our case. I do not say accelerometer is wrong or bad way, just we chose different path and it seems to work.

Our main robot is not holonomic and has other problems, so I cannot tell how exact it is in your case. For holonomic robot computing is easy if you know how much your motors have rotated.